# Google maps marker tooltip not working correctly, mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a bit of a problem with my Google map. I know the problem is to do with the loop and would like some info on a better way to tackle the problem

So let me being by painting you a picture; I have a map displaying locations via lat/lng  (pulled from the database). These markers have an addlistener attached to them that allows you to click them to bring up information, the problem is, when I click on any of the markers the tooltip will focus on the last item added to the map and bring up that markers' information. Which is ludicrous! (not the rapper)

I want to get a hammer and knock my map back into shape, not before some wise advice from you guys. Below is the codeling.

```
 function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng([REMOVED], [REMOVED]),
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
          mapOptions);
      // RAZOR BEGIN

       @foreach (var item in Model) {
<text>
      var markerlatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(@(item.latitude), @(item.longitude));
      var title = '@(item.address1)';
      var description = '@(item.averageRating)';
      var contentString = '<h3>' + title + '</h3>' + '<p>' + description + '</p>'

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: markerlatLng,
          title: title,
          map: map,
          draggable: false
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
          map.setZoom(15);
          map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
          //open a div on the mouse location?
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });

      </text>
  }     
      //RAZOR END
```

As you can see it loops through the model and gets the relevant information to be placed on the map.

I've tried placing the listener outside of the razor loop, but this just makes it not work atall.

As always, Stackoverflow, your help would be much, much appreciated.

PS. No cookies this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a confusion in how Razor/JS work together.

Remember that Razor is executed on the server side and javascript is executed on the client side, if you go to the page after it is loaded and see the source code you will see your problem. You are basically generating most of the javascript code once for each element in the model, which means that each variable will be declared several times.

What I would do (not sure if it's the best approach) is something like this:

```
<text>
// these are javascript arrays
var locations = [];
var descriptions = [];
</text>

@* This is the razor loop *@
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <text>
    locations.push(google.maps.LatLng(@(item.latitude), @(item.longitude)));
    descriptions.push('<h3>@(item.address1)</h3><p>@(item.averageRating)</p>');
  </text>
}

// Now using javascript, create a loop that will create the markers and assign the listeners
<text>
for(var i : locations){

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: descriptions[i];
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: locations[i],
      title: title,
      map: map,
      draggable: false
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      map.setZoom(15);
      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
      //open a div on the mouse location?
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
</text>
```

Another option would be to use a JSON Serializer in your Razor code, so you print the entire model as a JSON string and then just parse that in javascript instead of manually building the arrays.

Note that I didn't test this code so there might be some errors, but the idea is to get you on track.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense to me! I'll give this a lookie.